# How to display random letters in a grid view for an android word scramble puzzle

Tags: android, gridview, puzzle

I’m new to android game.

Please anybody help me how to do word scramble puzzle.

And the board looks like this(5x5 Grid ).

P  Q  E  T  T 
K  Z  I  Z  O 
K  M  I  M  P 
H  N  O  T  E 
R  O  I  B  X

Words can be composed of 
letters scanning horizontally (from 
left to right), vertically (from top to 
bottom) and diagonally (from upper‐
left to lower‐right or lower‐left to 
upper right). The same word cannot 
be formed more than once in the 
same location. For example, "top" 
can be found once, but "no" can be 
found in a few locations.

For example  fourth row horizontally(from left to right)there is a word **NOTE**

And first and second row  last column vertically(from top to bottom)there is a word **TO**

And third, fourth, fifth rows diagonally (upper –left to lower-right) there is a word **MOB**

Like this user can form as many words as he can.

How to mark user find words and on submit how to check with dictionary

whether the marked word is correct or not.

Any  help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are we freelancing on SO :P now?

Answer (score 2):

Put each letter in `ArrayList` of `String` then call

```
Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```

then set That `arraylist` to your `GridView` `adapter`